# Soft keypad remains on search input enter key

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would think this is a common pattern:

1. I have a jquery mobile searchbox `<input type="search"...>`
2. When entering enter, the submit is performed, but the keypad remains (on my android)
3. Keypad is hidden in my development envirnoment on desktop.

After lots of seaching, I've tried:

```
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    console.log("Im here");

    $('.ui-input-text').trigger('blur');

    $(this).trigger('blur');

    $("input").trigger('blur');

    $("#goSomewhereElse").focus();

    $('input#SearchText').blur(); 

}
```

Nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions on how to hide the keyboard?

Comment: is your `console.log` working?

Comment: You could try $(document).click(); or $(document.body).click(); or .trigger('touchstart'); in same manner

Comment: @Zlatev - I'm not sure about triggering events, but I know that events don't bubble to `document` level in iOS. Just something to keep in mind in case the above doesn't work

Comment: ahren, yes console log works.  Also, i even see the focus change while processing, so I know it gets in there. Just that when all is said and done, the keypad is still visible :(

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Zlatev, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Is the input inside a form? If it is try submitting it with `e.preventDefault()` beforehand or just `.submit(false).submit();`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) 
{
  window.location.hash = '#submit_chat_msg';
}
```

where 'submit_chat_msg' is ID of a button or something else.